# SQL query to find local max, min of date based data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following data set

```
Date         Category  
2014-01-01     A  
2014-01-02     A  
2014-01-03     A  
2014-01-04     B  
2014-01-05     B  
...  
2014-01-10     B  
2014-01-11     A  
...  
2014-01-20     A
```

The result I want to achieve is to find local min/max date for A and B, so as follows:

```
MinDate       MaxDate       Category  
2014-01-01    2014-01-03       A  
2014-01-04    2014-01-10       B  
2014-01-11    2014-01-20       A
```

Note: using

```
Select min(date), max(date), category from TABLE Group by category
```

will create the result

```
MinDate MaxDate Category  
2014-01-01 2014-01-20 A  
2014-01-04 2014-01-10 B
```

this is not what I want to achieve

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: There are only two categories, but three results. Do you mean once per contiguous (by date) category?

Comment: Exactly, I added a note to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a DBMS that supports window functions you can do this:

```
select category, grp, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
from (
    select category, date
         , row_number() over (order by date) 
         - row_number() over (partition by category order by date) as grp
    from T
) as X
group by category, grp
order by min(date)
```

The idea is to order all rows according to date and to order all rows in each category according to date. If the difference between these numbers changes it means that the chain of consecutive events for an category is broken by another category.

Comment: +1 Some extra explanantion: the difference between the `row_number()` increases when the next row switches from A to B.  When both rows have the same category the difference stays the same.

Comment: @Lennart I was reading the query since 10mn unable to understand until you add this explaination. That's pretty clever !

Comment: Lennart, thanks a lot for a fast response, the code returns the exact result I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Lennart, I was thinking of giving some ID to each group (category) but didn't know how. This is what is achieved with a grp column in your code. Brilliant :-)!